# AppCheck from CustomProvider showing as unverified:invalid request

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin, firebase-app-check

I recently deployed AppCheck on my firebase app, using a server to issue tokens for my custom provider. On the dashboard, I can see my requests labeled as unverified:invalid request (description: Requests with an invalid App Check token, which may be from an inauthentic client attempting to impersonate your app, or from emulated environments). The server utilizes Firebase Admin on same instance to issue tokens and everything looks good from there (I'm receiving the token and expiration in milliseconds). Is there any permission I need to allow to my server profile to ensure the requests are not labeled unverified? Thank you for your help on this!